# UserAgent regex going into infinite loop

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex for more "standard" User Agent strings.  So far I have

```
^(\w+)\/([\d+\.]+)+\s\((.+)+
```

Which gets me up to the closing parenthesis for the product/system information.  The problem is once I add `\)`, every regex engine I've put it through chokes and (I think) goes into an infinite loop.  Is there some sort of loop in here that I'm not seeing?

Comment: `([\d+\.]+)+` what are you trying to do here? And `(.+)+` here?

Comment: Generally speaking, nested quantifiers like `(.+)+` are the biggest performance problem in regex, because there are simply so many ways the engine could match a string with that pattern, it needs to do *lots* of backtracking.

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, regexes can't loop infinity unless you have an infinity large input.

Comment: do you have a sample input that we can use?

Comment: @h2ooooooo, the idea behind `([\d+\.]+)+` was to match any version string such as `1.1.1`, but any number of digits between the dots.  In retrospect, the other, `(.+)+\)` was a very sad attempt at saying "a string of any length before a `)`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something more like this:

```
(\w+)\/([\d.]+)\s*(?:\(([^)]+)\))?
```

---

Most of your performance was being killed when you did nested quantifiers like `([\d+\.]+)+`, which I think you mainly did out of not knowing exactly what you were working with.  This expanded explanation should help:

```
(       (?# start capture group #1)
 \w+    (?# match 1+ word characters)
)       (?# end capture group)
\/      (?# match / literally)
(       (?# start capture group #2)
 [\d.]+ (?# match 1+ digit or . characters)
)       (?# end capture group)
\s*     (?# match optional whitespace)
(?:     (?# start non-capturing group)
 \(     (?# match ( literally)
 (      (?# start capture group #3)
  [^)]+ (?# match 1+ non-) characters)
 )      (?# end capture group)
 \)     (?# match ) literally)
)?      (?# end optional non-capturing group)
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/tM2bE0)

---

This was partially based off your expression and my UA string: `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.92 Safari/537.36`.

As you can see you can have `\w+` (first group), followed by `/`, followed by `[\d.]+` (second group, the `.` has no special meaning in a character class and doesn't need to be escaped), followed by whitespace, followed by an optional set of data in parenthesis (the third group).

Comment: Well you just did what I was hoping to accomplish in about half the characters.  Thanks for the thorough explanation.

Comment: No problem, I believe my phone just said I had a comment asking about why `\s*` instead of `\s+`.  My reasoning is it makes it more "flexible" in an area where (in my opinion) we don't need to be "strict".  What if some random browser returns `Mozilla/5.0(X11)` for some reason?  I would still consider that a UA String.